# Inserting an empty row every time a keyword is encountered

Tags: r, insert, keyword

I have this dataset:

```
structure(list(Event = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Insert", 
"Ok"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Event", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

[image]

I would like to insert an empty row below every time there is an "Insert":

[image]

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a second method base on indexing by integer.  Here, I'll work with a character vector as this makes more sense given the data provided.

```
# get integer index with repeats for observations with "Insert"
myRows <- sort(c(seq_along(temp), which(temp == "Insert")))
# set second row index to missing
is.na(myRows) <- duplicated(myRows)
```

Now, feed this to index the character vector.

```
temp[myRows]
 [1] "Ok"     "Ok"     "Insert" NA       "Ok"     "Ok"     "Ok"     "Ok"     "Insert" NA       "Insert" NA       "Ok"    
[14] "Ok"     "Ok"     "Ok"     "Insert" NA       "Ok"     "Ok"     "Ok"     "Insert" NA
```

**data**

```
temp <-
structure(list(Event = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Insert", 
"Ok"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Event", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

temp <- as.character(temp$Event)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical vector

```
i1 <- df1$Event == "Insert"
Event <- unlist(lapply(split(df1$Event, 
    cumsum(c(TRUE, i1[-length(i1)]))), function(x) c(as.character(x), "")))
df2 <- data.frame(Event, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := cumsum(shift(Event == "Insert", fill = TRUE))
      ][, .SD[c(seq_len(.N), .N+1)] , grp
        ][is.na(Event), Event := ""
         ][, grp := NULL][]
#     Event
# 1:     Ok
# 2:     Ok
# 3: Insert
# 4:       
# 5:     Ok
# 6:     Ok
# 7:     Ok
# 8:     Ok
# 9: Insert
#10:       
#11: Insert
#12:       
#13:     Ok
#14:     Ok
#15:     Ok
#16:     Ok
#17: Insert
#18:       
#19:     Ok
#20:     Ok
#21:     Ok
#22: Insert
#23:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Event = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Insert", 
"Ok"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Event", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

mydf$rowindex <- 1:nrow(mydf)
mydf$repeats <- 1
mydf$repeats[which(mydf$Event=="Insert")] <- 2
mydf2 <- mydf[rep(mydf$rowindex,mydf$repeats),]
mydf2[which(grepl("\\.",row.names(mydf2))),"Event"] <- NA
```

Let me know if this helps.